# Nuxt Development server middleware `nuxt dev`

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, webpack-dev-server

I would like to customize Nuxt dev-server but I cannot find anything in the documentation that explain how to do it.

It seems the command `nuxt dev` launch a `webpack-dev-server` with hot module replacement, but if I extend the webpack configuration with a middleware for the devServer nothing happen.

My nuxt.config.js

```js
export default {
  build: {
    extend(config){
      config.devServer = {
        before: function () {
          console.log('I would like to do something here.');
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

#### EDIT

I've tried all the possible hooks Nuxt is providing, but there is no hook that fires before restarting the dev-server. There are hooks only after the server is restarted - that are `build:compiled` and `render:resourceLoaded`.

Comment: Here, you are extending the `build` command, not the `dev` one. If you do run `yarn build`, it should prompt the `console.log`.

Comment: I tried to replace the key `build` with `dev` but it still doesn't work. Moreover if I log outside the callback, for example inside the `extend` function it do `console.log` so I think `build` is the right key to customize `webpack` config. I am not sure Nuxt is using webpack dev server at this point.

Comment: At the end I am making my own watcher and I start it inside `build:before` hook.

Comment: Glad that this is working tho!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah my bad, it looks like `build` is actually be used even for `yarn dev`.
`dev` is probably not a config key that you can use.

`webpack-dev-server` is used by Nuxt, you can see it either in `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`.

There is no `before` key in the available configuration as seen here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build

It looks like `before` is only available as a Nuxt hook: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/internals-builder
Even tho, I'm not sure how to use this one.

Comment: There is `build:before` but it fires only the first time the `dev-server` start, not every time it reloads.

Comment: Because it's as the name suggests, **during** the build. You will need more of an `HMR` hook here. Nuxt's context do have an `isHMR`. Maybe `nuxt.hook('ready' ...)` could be a good start as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/internals-nuxt#hooks Also, I did not read this one but it may maybe help too: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/creating-a-nuxt-module#creating-our-module Otherwise, I don't really know much about Webpack so sorry if I cannot help any further.

Comment: Also, this one may help too: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7569

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately all those are firing only the first time. In the docs it says `build:compile` WHEN `Before webpack compile`. I believe on the `dev-server` there is compilation on HMR, therefore I will submit an issue.

Comment: Alright! Feel free to ask it in discussions also, this may be a more appropriate place for this kind of question: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/discussions I hope that I helped somehow. Have a great day!